# How can I replicate or mitigate this reported SQL Injection vulnerability?

Tags: sql-injection

We have a .Net WebForms-based website, hosted on IIS10 behind HAProxy on pfSense. We've performed many vulnerability scans and penetration tests on the site over the years, with only minor issues ever discovered and mitigated.

This week, one of our customers has run a scan and reported that the site has an apparent SQL Injection vulnerability. Aside from the fact that none of the data on the site is directly linked to a SQL server, we're struggling to understand this report, let along reproduce and mitigate it. We don't have any information on how the scan was performed, but we assume some kind of automated tests were carried out.

All of the reported vulnerabilities are in (DevExpress) ASPx controls on the site. For example, the report lists:

```
URI: https://oursite.ourcompany.com/
Parameter: popup_message%24btn_no
Attack: No' OR '1'='1' --
```

Where `popup_message` is a popup window control, and `btn_no` is a button on that page. Another example:

```
URI: https://oursite.ourcompany.com/
Parameter: de_timeonly
Attack: ZAP OR 1=1 --
```

where `de_timeonly` is a date editor control.

We have regular automated vulnerability scans running both externally and internally which haven't picked up on this perceived issue. If I run [sqlmap](https://sqlmap.org/) manually against the site, no vulnerabilities are detected, seemingly regardless of the parameters I'm using. For example:

```
./sqlmap.py -u https://oursite.ourcompany.com/ --dbms mssql -p "de_timeonly" --method POST
```

returns

> all testable parameters you provided are not present within the given
> request data

If I try

```
./sqlmap.py -u https://oursite.ourcompany.com/ --dbms mssql -p "de_timeonly" --method POST --random-agent --forms
```

it does a bunch of tests, ultimately telling me that there's no injectable parameters found.

Does anyone have any advice on how to replicate what the reporting scan has found, how to use `sqlmap` or any other testing tool properly on WebForms sites, or how to respond to the report and assure them that it's a false positive?

Comment: Using only test tools if you have the source code is pointless, look at the source code and check if it does not use vulnerable methods to build the query. Your target should be to eliminate all weaknesses not only vulnerabilities!

Comment: @Robert: I agree, and the application specifically doesn't have direct access to SQL, mainly for that reason. All the data it uses is abstracted through an internal API, and that API does (where it needs to) proper parameterised SQL. I'm 99% sure this is a "false positive", but I can't figure out why this particular test is picking this "vulnerability" up when others aren't - and, of course, we need to back up our assertion to the customer that it's not an issue.